# How to mark all TODO in emacs org mode as DONE or all "DONE" as "TODO"?

Tags: org-mode, emacs24

In emacs org mode, we can do task management, but what if I want to write a step-by-step instruction which has a number of TODOs. I will perform those TODOS, then mark them as DONE.

Now If I need to reuse that step-by-step instruction, is it possible if I can mark all the DONE items as TODO in one shot?

Comment: This [LINK](http://joelmccracken.github.io/entries/emacs-hack-set-todo-done-yesterday/) might help

Comment: I use an `re-search-forward` or `re-search-backward` and then perform actions when I reach a heading that matches -- this can be done within a selected region.  I find that `re-search-backward` works best because point will be at the beginning of the heading -- e.g., * DONE.

Answer (score 2):

This will change all  marked DONE to TODO, and ignore other headlines.

`(org-map-entries (lambda ()
          (when
              (string=
               (nth 2 (org-heading-components)) "DONE")
             (org-todo "TODO"))))`

Answer (score 0):

Throwing a couple of ideas:

- replace string "DONE" with M-%
- narrow to current buffer, display agenda will all "DONE" tasks, select them, and apply a bulk command to change state back to "TODO".

Answer (score 0):

I clone a task for that. You need to have your step-by-step guide always in `TODO` mode than, when you need to complete a guide, clone the parent task (`C-c C-x c`) and tick only the cloned tasks.